# Is passing values from 1 ObservableObject class to another ObservableObject class safe?

Tags: swiftui, viewmodel

My ViewModel is flooded with a ton of values, making it hard to read. I came up with this way to clean up the code. Everything works fine but it is really safe to use? What are the side effects (if any)?

```
class SampleValues: ObservableObject {
  @Published var tfName: String = ""
  @Published var tfPhone: String = ""

}

class MainClass: ObservableObject {
  @Published var sampleValues: SampleValues = SampleValues()
}
```

SampleView:

```
...
mainClassVM.sampleValues.tfName = "abc"
...
```

Comment: Use a struct instead

Comment: There is nothing inherently unsafe besides the normal concerns of thread safety, etc -- but nothing that has to do with `ObservableObject`. Whether or not it is a good architecture might be something to explore.

Comment: You might want to watch WWDC 2021’s [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290), in which they advise isolating published properties for the UI to the main actor.

Answer (score -1):

Since you tagged this question as SwiftUI you shouldn't even be using view model objects, thats the job of the `View` struct hierarchy and `@State` structs.